# Is it a fallacy to use Little's Law to prove that you need WIP limits in Kanban?

Tags: kanban

I have heard the argument that Little's Law proves that you should limit the work in process in your Kanban columns, because the more work that arrives, the longer it will take to move through the system.

Is this an accurate conclusion? If I have N items of work in the backlog, they all need to flow to "Done". So if I limit WIP to n, that will ensure that I am finishing the n items faster, but it also ensures that I have more work (N-n) left to do. So I am not convinced by the Little's Law argument.

What am I missing?

Comment: This question is more suited for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, Little's Law is a queue theory proof that describes the behaviour of queues. It says nothing about WIP limits. And it may not be as simple as increasing or decreasing WIP to get better lead-times.

Here is a blog post that discusses Little's Law in a bit more detail.

https://agileramblings.com/2012/12/11/littles-law-its-not-about-the-numbers/

The important part of Little's Law from a Kanban perspective is that it tells us with certainty what will happen to the other two parameters in the equation if we modify any one of the three parameters.

The other important component of Little's Law is that it is only useful if the 5 assumptions about the queue are true. You'll find the assumptions listed in the blog post above. The numbers that will come out of your Little's Law calculations at any point in time will differ if you are not able to satisfy the 5 assumptions required for the proof to work and as such, will provide questionable value to your decision-making process.